# Show a text box based on select box value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am wondering if someone could help me understand how I can achieve this. I want to show two input boxes only when a certain value in a select box is chosen using javascript (inc jquery).

My select box has this value:

```
<select name="menu-168" class="wpcf7-validates-as-required">
<option value="Residential">Residential</option>
<option value="Commercial">Commercial</option>
</select>
```

My input box has this value:

```
<input type="text" name="text-708" value="" class="wpcf7-validates-as-required" size="40">
```

In Pseudo code I am after something like this:

```
<if select name="menu-168" value = "Commerical">
<add css property ".hidden" to input name="text-708">
</if>
```

My javascript knowledge is so poor, would anyone mind showing me how this is done? This is a JSfiddle with the relevant HTML:

http://jsfiddle.net/K9zGP/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) to attach a listener on the select, to listen for a change event. With the change-event listener you can act whenever someone changes the selected option. Then you can use [`.toggle()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) to show/hide the input, depending on what the user has chosen in the select-list.

Something like this:

```
​$(function(){
    $("select[name='menu-168']").on("change", function (){           
        $("input[name='text-708']").toggle($(this).val() !== "Commercial");
    });
});​
```

[**Working example**](http://jsfiddle.net/K9zGP/10/)

In this example I use attribute selectors to select your elements, because there is nothing more exact to go on, but you could get slightly better performance by adding ID's to the relevant elements and use those for the selectors instead.

Comment: Thank you for this. It works for the most part, but the toggle bit doesn't seem to work. When you put it to residential it doesn't show the box again. Would this be an easy thing to integrate?

Comment: @user1738522 Sorry about that, that was a typo. I have updated the code and the example.

Answer (score 5):

This is using `jQuery`:

```
if ($("select[name='menu-168']").val() == "Commercial") {
    $("input[name='text-708']").addClass("hidden");
}​
```

On a side note, i would advise you to use class instead of names for referencing HTML elements. Class selection is much faster than attributes.

Comment: +1. OP - It's worth noting that you'll get much better performance using `class` or `id` selectors than `attribute` selectors.

Comment: Thank you! However I cant get it to work, am I doing something wrong here? http://jsfiddle.net/K9zGP/9/

Comment: this is only half the answer. Bind this to the select's change function using `on`.  See Christofer Eliasson's answer below.

Comment: @user1738522 if you want the whole solution (including binding), then Christofer Eliasson's answer should do it.

Comment: Thank you, I still upvoted your answer even though I didnt pick it

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#menu-168').on('change', function(){
    ($this).val() = "Commericial" ? 
        $('input[name='text-708']').show() : $('input[name='text-708']').hide();
    }
})
```